# How to read a pdf file in android application

Tags: android, pdf, dropbox

I am downloading a pdf file from dropbox, it is downloaded in my sdcard, how can i read it, i know many people have asked this question, but i have not found a good answer uptil now, any help or guidance would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Uri uri  = Uri.fromFile(mActivity.getFileStreamPath(mFileName));

    try
    {
        Intent intentUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intentUrl.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        intentUrl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        mActivity.startActivity(intentUrl);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "No PDF Viewer Installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, please explain few things, here mActivity is name of dropbox activity? can't i store the contents of pdf file into a string directly?